# Are Vision search (codes and text scanning) and Music Search still available in Windows Phone 10?

Tags: search, windows-10-mobile, music-search

In Windows Phone 7.5 and 8, you could [scan codes, tags and texts](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/web/scan-codes-tags-and-text), or [search for the name of a song](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/web/what-song-is-this) simply by pressing the `Search`[image: search button] button and then the `Vision`[image: vision button] or `Music`[image: music button] button, respectively.

These useful functionalities don't seem to be in Windows Phone 10. Did I miss something, or do I have to use some other apps (like Shazam for the music search) ?

Comment: You can ask Cortana what song is playing to find music.

Comment: I've read about that, but Cortana isn't available in my region (Switzerland, and french language). Thanks anyway...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, at least not yet and not even on the final WM10. If you have Cortana in your country you can ask her to id music or even shazam a song but the Vision and Music functions are currently not implemented which is a big shame as I you now need 2 more apps in your phone to perform these tasks (Shazam - SoundHound - Musicmatch.. and a QR reader like QR Scanner). Although the standalone apps' functionality far surpasses the previously inbuilt one, I hate when baked OS functionality is removed and I really hope it will be added in future versions.